# Horizontal ListViews inside a Vertical ScrollView are running slow

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

i am making an app which is similar to pulse and BBC News app

[image]

there are titles and beneath each title there is a horzintally scrolling image and text data

i done the horzintal listview part with this library: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

now everything is fine but the problem is the list is scrolling very slowly in the vertical way (its fine in the horizontal way in each row)

how can i solve this problem?

this is my function that adds the horizontal and the title part to the layout:

```
public void AddCategory(String CatTitle, List<CItem> ItemList) {
    LinearLayout thelayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

    HorizontialListView listview = new HorizontialListView(this, null);
    listview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, getPixels(100)));
    listview.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.categoryitemsbackground));

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        TextView tw;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // ///////////////////////////////////////////DO SOMETHING AFTER
            // CLICK PART ////////////////////////////////////////////
            tw = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemtitle);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    tw.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    CategoryAdapter mycategories = new CategoryAdapter(this,
            R.layout.categoryitem, ItemList);
    listview.setAdapter(mycategories);


    TextView textview=(TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.categorytitle, null);
textview.setText(CatTitle);
    thelayout.addView(textview);
    thelayout.addView(listview);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the BBC News app, they are not using `HorizontalListView` instead they are using `Gallery`. Please try using it.

Comment: Still you can use it. If you use `HorizontalListView` you need to add some math logic to avoid showing half of the item while scrolling which is already there in `Gallery`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use view pagers? They works better than Horizontal ListView and they aren't deprecated like Gallery.

Comment: im not sure viewpager is the way to go.i think its used for tabs (like 1 screen at a time and i need like 4-5 news at a time)